# Jquery autocomplete doesn't work from inside a lightbox

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm fetching a html document into a fancybox (lightbox). In this document I have an input field that I want to run jQuery UI Audocomplete on. It works as long as the input is outside of the lightbox, but not after the autocomplete function has been loaded. It seems like .autocomplete() is doing what it should and I get a json return, but it's not popping the value into the input. Any ideas?

Thanks for help!

```
 $(document).on('keydown', '.autocomplete', function(e) {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: "?ajax=autocomplete",
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have jsfiddle link or the markup for this ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I embed jQuery and jQuery UI and an external js file with the code above. I open a page within the page with http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Inside that page I have an input with the class autocomplete. Everything works as long as I'm not having the input inside the fancybox. I don't know if it is because everything loads first and then the input element shows up afterwards inside the fancybox. Like I mentioned the json return happens and looks identical to when it works, the value is just not showing up in the input. Like if the autocomplete stops after the fetch.

Comment: Any ideas or any more info I can give? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably it's working but you don't see it beacuse of lower z-index value. Please add parameter:

`open: function(){
            $('.ui-autocomplete').css('z-index', 99999999999999);
        }`